# Lista de páginas no enlazadas en los sitios de Stack Exchange

Tags: discusión, faq

> Esta publicación está basada en la pregunta [List of unlinked pages on Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76566/209901)

Aquí tenéis una lista de páginas especiales y no enlazadas (puede que lo estén en preguntas o respuestas, pero no siempre).

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Esta es una traducción de [la respuesta en inglés](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76569/209901). No dudes en añadir todo aquello que vaya añadiéndose en la respuesta original, así como corregir aquello que cambie.

## Páginas globales

#### Lista de sitios

- `/topbar/site-switcher/site-list`, por ejemplo https://es.stackoverflow.com/topbar/site-switcher/site-list
- puede accederse desde cualquier sitio, con contenido idéntico
- formato HTML

#### Preguntas populares en la red para móvil

- http://stackexchange.com/hot-questions-for-mobile
- Formato JSON (tienes que parsearlo manualmente)
- Usado por las aplicaciones móviles para mostrar las preguntas populares en la red

## Páginas propias de cada sitio

#### Elecciones a moderador de sitio

- `/election`, por ejemplo, [es.stackoverflow.com/election](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election)
- apunta a la elección en curso si hay una; de lo contrario, enseña un resumen de las elecciones pasadas.

#### Página de error

- `/error`, por ejemplo https://es.stackoverflow.com/error

#### Página de Captcha

- `/captcha`, por ejemplo, [es.stackoverflow.com/captcha](https://es.stackoverflow.com/captcha)

#### Página no encontrada

- `/404`, por ejemplo, [es.stackoverflow.com/404](https://es.stackoverflow.com/404)

#### Grandes éxitos

- `/questions/greatest-hits`, por ejemplo, [es.stackoverflow.com/questions/greatest-hits](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/greatest-hits)

#### Publicaciones anotadas

- `/annotated-posts`, por ejemplo, [es.stackoverflow.com/annotated-posts](https://es.stackoverflow.com/annotated-posts)

## Información por usuario

Para ver los elementos de esta sección debes tener una sesión iniciada. La información que recibes corresponde a tu cuenta.

#### Informe de reputación personal

- `/reputation`, por ejemplo, [es.stackoverflow.com/reputation](https://es.stackoverflow.com/reputation)
- Formato de texto plano
- También conocida como página de auditoría de la reputación. Más detalles [aquí](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation).

#### Buzón de entrada

- `/topbar/inbox`, por ejemplo https://es.stackoverflow.com/topbar/inbox
- puede accederse desde cualquier sitio, con contenido idéntico
- formato HTML
- `/topbar/achievements`, por ejemplo https://es.stackoverflow.com/topbar/achievements
- puede accederse desde cualquier sitio, con contenido idéntico
- formato HTML

#### Predicción de etiquetas

- `/users/tag-future/current`, por ejemplo, [es.stackoverflow.com/users/tag-future/current](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/tag-future/current)
- analiza qué etiquetas prefieres o evitas a la hora de contestar ([publicación de Meta relacionada](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194505/255554))
- la máquina no se ha vuelto a entrentar desde enero de 2014 (https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238638/213575)

## Información de las publicaciones

#### Historial de revisiones de pregunta

- `/posts/[number]/revisions`, por ejemplo, [meta.stackexchange.com/posts/76569/revisions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/76569/revisions)
- se muestra el enlace "historia" para las preguntas con al menos dos revisiones
- contiene enlaces a las revisiones individuales y su código fuente, así como un resumen de otros eventos como clausura, reapertura, (des)eliminación, inicio/fin de recompensas, (des)protección, tweets, marcado como (no) wiki de comunidad y uniones.

#### Vista cronográfica del historial de revisiones y votos

- `/posts/[question number]/timeline`, por ejemplo, [meta.stackexchange.com/posts/74983/timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/74983/timeline)
- para preguntas, muestra un resumen breve de respuestas y un enlace al cronograma de las respuestas; para respuestas, solo muestra las estadísticas de esa respuesta
- en diciembre de 2015, la vista cronográfica [fue rediseñada para contener más datos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271797/152859), copiada del cronograma de los moderadores, pero aún no está enlazada.

#### Elementos de revisión individuales

- `/review/[review type]/[review ID]`, por ejemplo, [es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5375800](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23287)
- cómo encontrar tus sugerencias de ediciones está descrito [aquí](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92602/146495).
- cómo encontrar el ID de una revisión cualquier está descrito [aquí](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248286/255554)
- las últimas revisiones se pueden encontrar fácilmente con las herramientas para usuarios de más de 10K de reputación.

## Páginas relacionadas con el chat

#### Últimos mensajes, historial extendido

- La pestaña de "recientes" mensajes de chat de un usuario tiene una paginación oculta. Simplemente añade `&page={N}` al final de la URL.
  por ejemplo: [chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9?tab=recent&page=86](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9?tab=recent&page=86)

#### Lista de los usuarios a los que se puede hacer ping en una sala

- `/rooms/pingable/[room number]` por ejemplo http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/pingable/89
- formato JSON (array de objetos)
- cada sala tiene una lista de usuarios a quien se puede hacer ping con `@`, que son los que están presentes en la sala en ese momento, o bien lo estuvieron en los últimos siete días y en algún momento del pasado escribieron algo.