# ¿Sabes inglés, quieres aportar a la comunidad de SOes y no sabes cómo? ¡Traduce un FAQ!

Tags: discusión, traducciones, llamada-a-la-accion

## En breve

> Esta pregunta **no** es un duplicado de [FAQ para sitios de Stack Exchange](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1378) porque esta propone una forma de aportar a la comunidad específicamente a **nuevos usuarios**. En mi opinión, los veteranos no requieren la orientación que aquí se da, además, el propósito de la otro pregunta es complementamente diferente, esa tiene el propósito de ser un índice de los FAQ que actualmente existen en español así como algunos enlaces externos.

La comunidad de SOes es joven, tiene poco más de un año considerando la fecha de lanzamiento de la beta privada, y hay mucho trabajo por hacer, particularmente atrayendo a nuevos miembros. Un instrumento muy útil para su rápida incorporación son los FAQ (acrónimo en inglés de Preguntas Frecuentes) pero también lo es **aprender haciendo**. Traducir un FAQ es una excelente forma de familiarizarse con la interfaz, dinámica y comunidad de Stack Overflow en Español ya que deja fuera, por un momento, el estrés de redactar un buena pregunta.

## Procedimiento propuesto

La dinámica propuesta es la siguiente:

1. Revisa :

   - [FAQ para sitios de Stack Exchange](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1378/)
   - http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53106/
2. Escoge un tema de los listados [a continuación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1381/65) con base en tus intereses personales considerando aportar algo de valor para la comunidad de SOes.
3. Publica en http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53106/  tu intención y comenta cómo y cuando harías la traducción
4. Publica tu el FAQ siguiendo las pautas indicadas en [FAQ para sitios de Stack Exchange](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1378/)
5. Si tienes privilegios de edición, tacha el enlace correspondiente al artículo que has traducido, en caso contrario, publica una respuesta.

## Preguntas relacionadas

> ordenadas por su id

- [¿Son aceptables las traducciones directas de respuestas de StackOverflow en inglés?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/14/)
- [¿Son aceptables las traducciones de preguntas de StackOverflow en inglés?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/46/)
- [Sugerencias de mejora en las traducciones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/83/)

## Otra propuesta similar

- [Preguntas con enlaces cruzados: identifiquemos las ya existentes en este sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1320/)

## Relacionado

- [Help develop the site and community knowledge base in your language](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319024/289691)

Answer (score 4):

---

> Traducción semi-automática de [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)

## FAQ de la Comunidad

**Para los sitios en la red Stack Exchange 2.0**

Para ver una lista de palabras y frases de uso común, ver el [Glosario](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/40353).

Para una guía oficial de Stack Exchange, visite el [Centro de ayuda](//meta.stackexchange.com/help).

### Haciendo preguntas

- <s>[How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647)</s>     → [¿Cómo escribo un buen título?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4774/83)
- <s>[How can I get answers fast?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8010)</s>      → [¿Cómo consigo respuestas rápidamente?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1445/83)
- [Where can I ask a question about finding general software that meets certain requirements?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199411)
- [How should we deal with Google questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8724)
- <s>[What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)</s>    → [¿Qué es el Problema XY?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3360)
- [How do I get attention for one of my own questions without a good answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046)
- [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997)
- [What can I do when getting “This question body does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92074)
- [Should questions include "tags" in their titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190)
- [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068)
- [Do I have to worry about copyright issues for code posted on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12527)

### Respondiendo preguntas

- <s>[What is an acceptable answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118582)</s>    → [¿Qué es una respuesta aceptable?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/958/83)
- [How do I write a good answer to a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7656)
- [How should you respond to "Give me a fish" / RTFM questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2686)
- [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227)
- [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231)
- [Can I answer my own questions, even if I knew the answer before asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463)

### Se aceptan respuestas

- <s>[How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234)</s>     → [¿Cómo funciona la aceptación de respuestas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427/83)
- [How do I see which of my questions are not accepted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86274)

### Trabajar con mensajes

- ¿Qué significa cuando una pregunta o respuesta es ...
- [cerrada, o puesta en espera] [2](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10582)?
- [bloqueada] [3](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/22228)?
- <s>[eliminada] [4](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)</s>  [¿Cómo funciona la eliminación de publicaciones? ¿Por qué podría eliminarse una publicación y qué implica? ¿Cuál es el criterio para eliminar?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1033/83)?
- [protegida] [5](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/52764)?
- [How do you reopen a closed question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36415)
- [How do question bookmarks work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53585)
- <s>[What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740)</s>    → [¿Qué es una publicación "Wiki de comunidad"?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317/83)
- [Who is the Community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19738)
- [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065)
- [What is a historical lock, and what is it used for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126587)
- <s>[Why does the "Unanswered Questions" tab show questions that have answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18870)</s>    → [¿Por qué la pestaña "Sin responder" muestra preguntas que tienen respuestas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1576/83)
- [View or search for unanswered questions with a certain tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18545)
- [How do you challenge the closing of one of your questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19126)
- [How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841)
- [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249)
- [What are these notices above my post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165006)

### Comentarios

- [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756)
- <s>[Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173)</s>    → [¿Por qué necesito 50 puntos de reputación para comentar? ¿Qué alternativa tengo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/83)
- <s>[How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019)</s>    → [¿Cómo funcionan las @respuestas en los comentarios?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1357/83)
- [How do I view the recent replies to things I have written?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45708)
- [Is it acceptable to write a thank you in a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126180)

### Etiqueta

- [Are taglines & signatures disallowed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5029)
- [Are expletives (cursing, swear words or vulgar language) allowed on SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22232)
- [Embrace the non-Googlers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5280)
- <s>[Thanking users who answered my question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17878)</s>    → [¿Cómo dar las gracias a los usuarios que responden a mis preguntas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1624/83)
- [What is the etiquette for correcting old questions with incorrect answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5408)
- [Etiquette for voting to close your own questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5215)
- [Answer or comment: what's the etiquette?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17447)
- [What to do when plagiarism is discovered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160071)
- [What should I do if a user posts sensitive information as part of a question or answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132117)

### Promoción

- [How can I link to an external resource in a community-friendly way?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94022)
- [Limits for self-promotion in answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57497)
- [What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58032)

### Edición y formato

- [How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21788)
- [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251)
- <s>[Why is the edit button disabled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81681)</s>    → [¿Por qué está deshabilitado el botón de editar?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1579/83)
- <s>[What is a 'rollback'?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17038)</s>    → [¿Qué es una 'reversión'?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/816/83)
- [Why can any user edit any other user's question or answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120576)
- [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)
- [Denoting keyboard shortcuts in Stack Exchange posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19145)
- [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1777)
- [How to nest code within a list using Markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3792)
- [How do I create a screenshot to illustrate a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99734)
- [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75491)
- [What's the recommended syntax for an image with a link?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2133)
- [What should I keep out of my posts and titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131009)
- [Why does the Community user approve and reject edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184992)
- <s>[What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108)</s>    → [¿Qué es el resaltado de sintaxis? ¿Cómo funciona?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1463/83)

### Etiquetado

- [How do I search for questions with (or without) specific tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5229)
- [How do I correctly tag my questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18878)
- <s>[How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or "zombie") tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19753)</s>   [He creado una etiqueta accidentalmente, ¿cómo puedo borrarla?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3115/83)
- [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70710)
- [Filtering questions by multiple tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17003)
- [Why do we tag questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31776)
- [What do icons on the tags mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/30187)
- [What do "watched tags" and "ignored tags" do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19173)
- <s>[When should I create a new tag? How do I request a new tag if I don't have enough rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146949)</s>    → [¿Cómo crear o solicitar una nueva etiqueta?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/440/83)

### Reputación, medallas, y la votación

- [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237)
- [How do "badges" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17853)
- [How long does it take for badges to be awarded? How are they generated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1716)
- <s>[What are the badges I can earn on each site, and what are the exact criteria for earning each badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397)</s>   [Lista de todas las medallas con su descripción completa](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2699/83)
- [What are the limits on how I can cast, change, and retract votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5212)
- <s>[When should I vote?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130046)</s>    → [¿Cuándo debería votar?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1075/83)
- [How does comment voting and flagging work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17364)
- [How do I audit my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43004)
- [Why did I receive a message saying I have been granted a privilege, yet I don't have enough reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73673)
- [What are the limits and restrictions for new users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4564)
- <s>[What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829)</s>    → [¿Qué es el voto serial y cómo me afecta?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/663/83)
- [How does the SO voter fraud detection mechanism work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19920)
- [What does "user was removed" mean and why did my reputation change because of it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126470)
- [How do I read the history of my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139614)
- [What are the reputation requirements for privileges on sites, and how do they differ per site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58587)

### Moderación

- [Who are the diamond moderators, and what is their role?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75189)
- [What are the moderation tools available to 10,000+ reputation users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4565)
- [Flagging a post for moderator review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/24560)
- <s>[How do I properly use the "Not an Answer" flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073)</s>   [¿Cómo uso correctamente el reporte "No es una respuesta"?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2973/83)
- [What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58032)
- [Should I edit a question or answer with offensive content?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22194)
- [What is the etiquette for modifying posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11474)
- [Should an answer that encourages illegal activity be marked as "Offensive"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8492)
- [Should moderators enforce NDAs for software vendors?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94465)
- [I think I found some user accounts that should be merged; what do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98399)
- <s>[Who is on the Community Management Team, and what do they do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99338)</s>    → [¿Quiénes forman el Community Team? ¿Qué hacen?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1670/83)
- [What are the review queues, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161390)
- [What are the guidelines for reviewing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155538)
- [What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157121)
- <s>[What is a disputed flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95275)</s>   https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts
- [Why does flag marking as helpful/declined not always correlate with moderator action?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105391)

### Búsqueda y fuentes RSS

- [How do I search for questions with (or without) specific tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5229)
- [How do I make search return results that actually contain all the search terms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14898)
- [RSS feed for responses to your posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21756)

### Cuentas, registro e inicio de sesión

- [Why should I register my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557)
- [How can one link / merge / combine / associate two accounts / users? (Anonymous / unregistered / cookie, or Google / Facebook / registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18232)
- [Can't log in with my OpenID - Troubleshooting Tips](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1774)
- [How do I change my login provider(s)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/793)
- [How do I remove an OpenID or login?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22223)
- [How do I change my profile picture, or avatar?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41277)
- [Why is my gravatar on Meta Stack Overflow different from my gravatar on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1681)
- [How is the default user avatar generated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17443)
- [My account has been temporarily suspended; what does that mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125268)
- [How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5999)
- [How do I contact other users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57537)
- [How can I log in to my Stack Exchange account if my current account provider is blocked?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138994)
- [I lost control of my account before registering, can it be recovered?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95358)
- [Why can't I use Stack Exchange if I'm under 13 years old, and is there any way I can use it legally?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61770)

### Otros

- [How often do CAPTCHAs appear?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1343)
- [What is an SE "day"? When does each day start?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/27199)
- <s>[Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161)</s>    → [Cuáles navegadores están soportados y qué más necesito para usar los sitios de Stack Exchange?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1600/)
- [Is Stack Overflow's content protected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60455)
- [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677)
- [What third-party tools are there for the trilogy websites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5188)
- [Who owns the content I post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18221)
- [What makes a winning site proposal?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52066)
- [How can I propose a new site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76974)
- [What can cause a question to be bumped?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48578)
- [How do I remove my name from a post, in accordance with CC BY-SA?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96732)
- [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445)
- [How are Stack Exchange sites officially branded?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9024)
- [Which tools and technologies are used to build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10369) ([blog post](//blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/))
- <s>[List of unlinked pages on Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76566)</s>    → [Lista de páginas no enlazadas en los sitios de Stack Exchange](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1157/83)
- [Where do the names of the Stack Overflow trilogy sites come from?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61541)
- [How can I get Stack Exchange to send me to a conference?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132282)
- [Do Stack Overflow and other Stack Exchange sites have an app I can use?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/154797)
- [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899)
- [Which links and sites are handled specially in chat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57286)
- [What shortened URLs are available through s.tk?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109795)
- [What are the permissions the Android app needs?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217345)
- [What is the weekly newsletter? Who composes them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121630)
- [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What should I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177)
- [Is Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow available for private or internal use?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16054)

### Preguntas en sitios específicos

#### Stack Overflow

- [Should I send students to Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254433)
- [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)
- [What are the rules on using the Stack Overflow logo?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22117)
- [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428)
- [When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260245)
- [Before you post your next question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254262)
- [What is the proper way to approach Stack Overflow as someone totally new to programming?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254572)

#### Meta Stack Exchange

- [How does Meta Stack Exchange work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/47634)
- [The Many Memes of Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19478)
- [Do posts have to be in English on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676)
- [Why are the moderators being so strict with quality related flags recently?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160754)

#### Solicitudes de características nuevas

- [How do I write a good feature request?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258136/289691) (faq-proposed)

#### Otros

- [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598)

### Enlaces externos

- [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)
- [Help Vampires](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/)
- [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)
- [Writing the Perfect Question by Jon Skeet](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
- <s>[How to Ask Questions the Smart Way](http://catb.org/%7Eesr/faqs/smart-questions.html)</s>  [Cómo hacer preguntas de manera inteligente](https://sindominio.net/ayuda/preguntas-inteligentes.html)
- [What have you tried?](//mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)
- [Ten Simple Rules for Getting Help from Online Scientific Communities](http://www.ploscompbiol.org/article/info:doi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pcbi.1002202)

---

### ¿Tu pregunta no forma parte de la FAQ?

Primero mira las preguntas etiquetadas [meta-tag: faq-proposed] para ver si hay una pregunta no en este índice que podría tener la respuesta que buscas. Si todavía no puedes encontrar una respuesta, consulta las siguientes instrucciones para proponer que una pregunta sea incluída en las preguntas frecuentes.

#### ¿Cómo puede una pregunta añadirse a esta lista?

- Redacta la pregunta de forma lisa y llana en el cuerpo de la pregunta.
  La respuesta va en una respuesta.
- **Volver** a este índice. Pega esto al final de la pregunta:

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](/q/7931)

- Marcar como [meta-tag: faq-proposed] y [meta-tag: support].  Cuando una publicación parece
  que ha alcanzado un estado maduro, un moderador le agregará [tag: FAQ].
- Repórtala para que un moderador la marque como **wiki de la comunidad**.  Cualquier publicación que sea una Preguntas frecuentes que aún no esté marcada como
  wiki de la comunidad debe ser marcada como tal.
- Después de que la publicación tiene añadida la etiqueta [faq](/questions/tagged/faq), añadir un enlace en el [índice](/q/7931) anterior.

---

Enlace a sala de chat derivada de comentarios en esta publicación los cuales "ya no son necesarios", sin embargo, podría ser interesante consultarlos en un futuro:

[Continuemos en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56707/discussion-between-ruben-and-fedorqui)

Comment: _How do I search for questions with (or without) specific tags?_ está dos veces, pero tiene sentido en los dos casos.

Comment: Al agregar el enlace a la ¿Qué es el Problema XY? dejaron de mostrarse los títulos de las preguntas de Meta SE. ¡¡¡¿¿¿????!!!

Comment: ostras! Pues no parece que haya cambiado el [criterio de conversión de links automáticamente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/108475/209901) que explicaba Mariano en [¿Cuándo se convierte un enlace en el título de una pregunta? ¿Hay algún límite?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1710/83)