# ¿Cómo consigo respuestas rápidamente?

Tags: soporte, faq, respuesta, preguntas

> Esta es una traducción de la pregunta [How can I get answers fast?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8010/209901)

¿Cómo formulo una pregunta de manera que consiga respuestas rápidamente? Veo preguntas que son bastante viejas y siguen sin recibir respuestas, mientras que otras obtienen respuestas muy rápidamente.

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Esta es una traducción de la respuesta aceptada en [How can I get answers fast?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8010/209901)

He aquí algunos factores:

- Haz preguntas claras y respondibles.
- Esfuérzate en el título.
- Etiqueta la pregunta correctamente.
- Edita y mejora la pregunta hasta que esté perfecta.
- Ten la suerte de que el experto en esa materia vea tu pregunta.