# ¿Por qué la pestaña "Sin responder" muestra preguntas que tienen respuestas?

Tags: soporte, faq, preguntas-no-contestadas

> Esto es una traducción de [Why does the “Unanswered Questions” tab show questions that have answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18870/209901)

¿Por qué la pestaña "Sin responder" muestra preguntas que tienen respuestas?

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Esto es una traducción de la respuesta aceptada en [Why does the “Unanswered Questions” tab show questions that have answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18871/209901). Corrige todo aquello que veas que no es correcto o necesite mejora.

La pestaña [*Sin responder*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest) [muestra preguntas](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/) que no tienen respuestas con puntuación total positiva ni respuestas aceptadas, y que no fueron cerradas. Esto incluye también preguntas sin ninguna respuesta.

La pestaña [*no hay respuestas*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers), muestra las preguntas que no tuvieron absolutamente ninguna respuesta.

Comment: Excelente información. Significa que una pregunta con respuesta es aquella marcada como resuelta y/o aquella que tenga al menos una respuesta con voto positivo, sea ésta marcada como correcta por el OP o no.