# ¿Por qué está deshabilitado el botón de editar?

Tags: soporte, faq, ediciones-sugeridas

> Esta es una traducción de [Why is the edit button disabled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81681/209901)

Edité algunas publicaciones en el pasado, pero ahora no puedo apretar en el botón de "editar". Pensé que era un problema con una pregunta en cuestión, pero parece que no puedo apretar dicho botón en ninguna publicación.

¿Qué está pasando?

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Esto es una traducción de la respuesta aceptada en [Why is the edit button disabled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81701/209901). Corrige todo aquello que veas que no es correcto o necesite mejora.

Hay una serie de situaciones en las que no se aceptan sugerencias de ediciones:

1. Un gran número de tus sugerencias de ediciones fueron rechazadas durante la última semana (al menos [5 más que un tercio de tus ediciones aceptadas](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91392/too-many-of-your-edits-were-rejected-try-again-in-7-days/92337#92337)).
2. No tenemos espacio en la cola (40, con algunas excepciones. Mira [aquí](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84362/whats-the-fixed-size-of-the-suggested-edit-queue/84398#84398) para más detalles)
3. Tienes 5 sugerencias de edición pendientes.
4. Hay una edición a esta publicación en particular que aún no ha sido aprobada.
5. No has iniciado la sesión y la publicación fue publicada hace menos de 10 minutos.
6. Estás en un *child Meta*. Es decir, en el sitio Meta *hijo* de un sitio principal.
7. Tu cuenta está suspendida.
8. La publicación está bloqueada.

En el pasado, no aparecía el enlace editar; desde julio de 2012 dicho enlace [aparece inhabilitado](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91172/always-show-the-edit-button-on-questions/138944#138944) y al pasar el ratón por encima se muestra un cuadro emergente con información de por qué no se puede sugerir la edición, diciendo por ejemplo "La cuenta no tiene permitido sugerir ediciones".

Comment: @Mariano aaaah qué bien visto, no caí en ello. Me parece que sí, podríamos estandarizar el concepto _meta hijo_ para estos casos. En cuanto a la reputación, ahora mismo con 5 se puede participar en todas (de [Reputation requirements compared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160292/209901)), si bien me consta que en el pasado se cambió el umbral (no encuentro referencias ahora mismo).