# Veo mal publicaciones de snippets en un antiguo navegador

Tags: bug, stack-snippets, navegador-web

Verán, tengo una computadora de 960 MB de RAM, no pienso usar Firefox, ya con este navegador me está usando el %55 de la memoria, en cambio estoy usando un fork de Firefox, que se llama ***Basilisk, en la versión 2018.02.02 (64 bits)***.

Les comparto cómo se ven las preguntas con snippets:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A esta altura en mi opinión, si era por el tema de compatibilidad ya SO no debería usar jQuery, bueno, no me gusta mucho ese framework, pero si es por tema de practicidad al programar el sitio lo entiendo.

Dejando ese comentario a parte, ¿Es posible hacer que no se sobreponga el snippet con los comentarios? Les dejé la versión, si quieren pueden instalarlo en sus sistemas para ver que es cierto.

No pienso actualizar el navegador porque le quitaron muchas cosas, según los desarrolladores por problemas de seguridad, lo cual no me preocupa en lo más mínimo.

Comment: Esto deberias preguntarlo en Meta General [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com)... nosostros solo somos uno de los sitios de la red.. ahi te diran si se puede hacer algo o no...

Comment: @gbianchi Entiendo, lo tendré en cuenta, gracias por el enlace, no lo tenía en mis marcadores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pregunta en Meta SE derivada de esta: [Snippet posts look bad in an old browser](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364920/289691)

---

Si estas usando un navegador muy particular, antes de hacer un reporte de bug sería bueno que investigaras si ese navegador está entre los navegadores soportados. Empieza por revisar el Centro de Ayuda y las publicaciones sobre el tema aquí y si sabes inglés en Meta SE también sobre los navegadores "admitidos" y las tecnologías usadas.

Si encuentras que se trata de un bug que afecta a cualquier sitio de la la red de SE, lo mejor es hacer la publicación directamente en Meta SE. Si necesitas ayuda para lograr que en tu navegador funcione y/o se vea mejor el sitio sin tener que actualizarlo, entonces sería mejor usar la etiqueta [soporte](/questions/tagged/soporte) o bien preguntar en un sitio como [Super User](https://superuser.com).

Artículo de ayuda relacionado

- [¿Qué navegadores admitimos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/browser-support)

Preguntas de meta relacionadas

- [Cuáles navegadores están soportados y qué más necesito para usar los sitios de Stack Exchange?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1600/65)
- [¿Qué es Stack Snippet?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3292/65)
- [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/289691)
- [What is our stance on questions specific to unsupported browsers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349371/289691)

Comment: La respuesta está bien, aunque la frase, __"las dos últimas versiones estables de los principales navegadores"__, no es sostenible en el tiempo, y no hace referencia a alguno en particular, no dice explícitamente Firefox.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que no es sostenible en el tiempo?¿Por qué sería necesario que diga explícitamente un navegador y cómo eso haría lo que sea a lo que te refieres "sostenible en el tiempo"? P.S. Esto seguramente amerita su propia pregunta.

Comment: Tampoco dice cuántos navegadores principales... Si en algún momento los principales fueran otros, entonces StackOverflow soportaría los principales que fueron en una fecha específica, pero no los principales del momento actual, además, uno no puede asegurarse que siempre será compatible con las dos últimas versiones, algún día pueden hacer un cambio grande en el navegador que dejaría inutilizable el sitio web.

Comment: No le veo sentido discutir aquí el contenido de artículo de ayuda en cuestión. Si lo que estás buscando es discutir ese artículo te sugiero publicar una pregunta en [meta.se].

Comment: Entiendo, tendré en cuenta eso.