# ¿Cuándo se convierte un enlace en el título de una pregunta? ¿Hay algún límite?

Tags: soporte, formato, enlaces

En una respuesta, intenté usar una URL "[al descubierto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#bare-urls)", para que se convierta automáticamente en el título de la pregunta.

Me funcionó con: `https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/47634/304899`
que se transforma en: [How does Meta Stack Exchange work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/47634/304899)

Pero no funciona con: `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260245/5290909`
que se ve: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260245/5290909

¿Por qué no se convierte?
¿Hay algún límite?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) (SOes), sólo se transforman automáticamente los enlaces a preguntas de:

- [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) (SOes)
- [Stack Overflow Meta en español](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/) (mSOes)

En [Stack Overflow Meta en español](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/) (mSOes) se transforman automáticamente los enlaces a preguntas de:

- [Stack Overflow Meta en español](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/) (mSOes)
- [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) (SOes)
- [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) (MSE)

---

Esto se menciona en *[What limitations does converting question links to links with titles have?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108134/304899)*.

1. Los enlaces dentro del mismo sitio son ilimitados.

2. Los enlaces a otros sitios están limitados por:
   a) 5 sitios máximo.
   b) N preguntas por sitio, donde N es 40 en metas y 10 en sitios principales.

3. Mientras que los enlaces dentro del mismo sitio siempre funcionan, se convierte el enlace a otros sitios dependiendo de dónde estés:
   a) En todos los subsitios (actualmente no hay), funcionan los enlaces al sitio maestro y vice-versa.
   b) En todos los metas, funcionan los enlaces al principal y vice-versa.
   c) En Meta Stack Exchange, funcionan *todos* los enlaces a otros sitios.
   d) En todos los metas, funcionan los enlaces a Meta Stack Exchange.
   e) Todo lo demás no funciona.

**Hice un diagrama de esto:**

[image: Enlaces permitidos]