# ¿Una agradable sorpresa? ¿Desde cuándo funciona el autocompletado de títulos?

Tags: soporte, formato, enlaces

Hoy me llevé una agradable sorpresa.

Siempre que indico el enlace a una pregunta de SO me gusta usar el enlace que obtengo desde `compartir`, o sea, los enlaces como este:

`https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/72719/29967`.

Antes tenía que hacer todo esto:

1. En la pregunta que quiero enlazar, copiar el título de la pregunta
2. En la respuesta donde quiero enlazar, pegar el título de la pregunta
3. En la pregunta que quiero enlazar, copiar la url desde `compartir`
4. En la respuesta, subrayar el título de la pregunta pegado anteriormente
5. En la respuesta, seleccionar la opción de `enlace` en el editor
6. En el cuadro de diálogo de enlace, pegar el enlace

**Pero hoy**, al hacer los pasos 1 y 2 ocurrió algo mágico:

Escribí: `https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/72719/29967` y apareció:

**[¿Cuál es la diferencia entre echo, print, print_r, var_dump y var_export en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/72719/29967)**

**¡Apareció la pregunta enlazada con su título!**

¡Adiós a los pasos 3,4,5 y 6!

**¿Eso no existía antes, verdad? ¿Desde cuándo existe?**

Comment: No sé desde cuándo pero ya existía cuando se lanzó SOes

Comment: En SOen lleva bastante tiempo, pero no te se decir exactamente cuanto. Aquí hace unos meses no funcionaba pero ya lleva un par de meses o tres en funcionamiento.

Comment: @FranciscoRomero me extraña lo que comentas, a mí me ha funcionado desde el primer día.

Comment: @fedorqui Pues a mí en varias respuestas me salía el link simplemente sin salirme el título. De hecho, creo que en algunas el usuario Comunidad me las modificó después para poner el título de la pregunta enlazada en cuestión. Luego busco algún ejemplo y lo pongo.

Comment: @FranciscoRomero En el contexto de la migración de HTTP a HTTPS ([Network-wide HTTPS: It's time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058/209901)) el usuario Comunidad modificó todos los enlaces dentro de la red Stack Exchange para convertir los HTTP en HTTPS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pues resulta que esto está presente desde tiempos inmemoriales. De [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/59446#59446) (título puesto usando este autocompletado):

> - 2010-11-05: Posting links to the very same site now automatically [shows the  title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49433/replace-trilogy-raw-links-with-the-current-question-title/69483#69483). So, just insert `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/whatever.` to become [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/whatever).  The title is not updated when it changes, unless the post is edited. It does not work in comments, nor for links to other SOFU sites. Trailing punctuation marks such as a comma, dot or question mark (without URL parameters) to get a readable sentence work just fine.

Es decir:

> - 5 noviembre 2010: Publicar enlaces al mismo sitio ahora [muestra el título](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49433/replace-trilogy-raw-links-with-the-current-question-title/69483#69483) automáticamente. Así que escribe `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/whatever.` y verás cómo se convierte en [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/whatever).  El título no se actualiza cuando cambia, a menos que la publicación se edite. No funciona en los comentarios, ni en enlaces fuera de los sitios SOFU [Stack Overflow, Super User y Server Fault]. Se pueden usar signos de puntuación al final, como la coma, el punto o la interrogación (sin parámetros URL) para que la frase sea más leíble.

Es importante destacar que la información sobre los enlaces fuera de SOFU es algo obsoleta, pues el autocompletado funciona entre sitios en los casos descritos por Mariano en [¿Cuándo se convierte un enlace en el título de una pregunta? ¿Hay algún límite?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1710/83)

También es importante destacar que este autocompletado funciona solamente para enlazar preguntas, no para enlazar respuestas:

- [¿Una agradable sorpresa? ¿Desde cuándo funciona el autocompletado de títulos?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2812/83) (tu pregunta → se autocompleta correctamente)
- https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2815/83 (mi respuesta → no se autocompleta)

Comment: Por cierto, el otro día descubrí que en los comentarios el "title" incluye el título de la pregunta si la pones completa, con la parte de "questions": https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2812/una-agradable-sorpresa-desde-cu%C3%A1ndo-funciona-el-autocompletado-de-t%C3%ADtulos (pasa el cursor por encima y verás que se expande a "una agradable sorpresa desde cu%25C3%25A1ndo funciona el autocompletado de t%25C3%25ADtulos") Si pegas el enlace de "compartir" no funciona: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2812/83

Comment: ¿Por qué no funcionará para enlazar respuestas?

Comment: @A.Cedano buena pregunta. Veo que se ha comentado en [meta.se] diferentes veces: [Links to answers are not formatted to show the title automatically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128330/209901) y no hay respuesta oficial al respecto. Puede que tenga que ver con las [limitaciones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/108475/209901) que imponen para no saturar el sistema (pura especulación mía).