# Hagamos que los enlaces a Stack Overflow en inglés se conviertan automáticamente en título de la pregunta

Tags: característica-nueva, formato, enlaces

Como se explica en [¿Cuándo se convierte un enlace en el título de una pregunta? ¿Hay algún límite?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1710/83), en la red Stack Exchange existe la funcionalidad de que dado un enlace tipo `https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1710/83`, es decir, a una pregunta, este se convierte automáticamente al título de la pregunta en el momento de escribirlo.

Por tanto, `https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1710/83` se convierte en [¿Cuándo se convierte un enlace en el título de una pregunta? ¿Hay algún límite?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1710/83) (mirad el código fuente para comprobar que no he escrito nada, solamente el enlace).

Tal y como comentaba Mariano en [su respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1711/83), actualmente la completación de títulos va así:

> [image: Enlaces permitidos]

Lo que quiere decir que

> En [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) (SOes), sólo se transforman automáticamente los enlaces a preguntas de:
>
> - [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) (SOes)
> - [Stack Overflow Meta en español](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/) (mSOes)

Sin embargo, por la naturaleza del sitio, es muy común enlazar preguntas de Stack Overflow en inglés y algo engorroso tener que copiar el título cada vez. Por ello, **¿podría añadirse esta funcionalidad de manera que las publicaciones de SOen se autocompleten en SOes?**

Comment: Muy buena petición! Está Nicolas al tanto?

Comment: esto no es mas para MSE que para aca? o vos decis que lo podemos hacer nosotros?

Comment: @lois6b buen apunte, se lo acabo de comentar en The Terminal. ¡Gracias!

Comment: @gbianchi bueno si tiene buena acogida aquí luego publicaría en MSE diciendo _oye que en SOes lo quieren mucho mucho_ :)

Comment: nosotros queremos todo mucho mucho.. :P

Comment: Me parece una excelente idea. Sabemos si en otros sitios internacionales (portugues, ruso..) está implementado?

Comment: @Pikoh no me consta y no lo creo. Acabo de hacer una prueba en SOpt y no me funciona: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/193250/28073 tampoco en los otros: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/30397/19559 y https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/837486/193685

Comment: @fedorqui estupendo, era por comprobar si la funcionalidad ya estaba implantada en algún otro sitio internacional dado que creo que sería útil en todos ellos y que así el proceso fuera mas sencillo. A ver si nos hacen caso en esto...

Comment: Se echa de menos a Mariano :(