# He creado una etiqueta accidentalmente, ¿cómo puedo borrarla?

Tags: soporte, faq, etiquetas

He creado la etiqueta [team-services](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/team-services) para una pregunta pero después he visto que ya estaba creada la etiqueta [vsts](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsts) (Visual Studio Team Services), que es además la que se utiliza en el sitio en inglés.

Sería mejor eliminarla para no tener dos etiquetas sobre el mismo concepto pero no tengo privilegios suficientes, ni he encontrado forma de proponer la eliminación (a parte de por aquí).

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Asegúrate que no la use nadie y será borrada:

- elimina la etiqueta de todas aquellas preguntas que la tengan.
- una vez hecho esto, ¡ya está! Todas las etiquetas que no tienen asociada ninguna pregunta se eliminan automáticamente, a través de un script que se ejecuta diariamente a las 3.00 UTC.

<sub>Extraído de [I accidentally created a tag. How do I delete it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71124/368819) y [How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or “zombie”) tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19753/209901)</sub>