# ¿Qué es el Problema XY?

Tags: soporte, faq

¿Qué es el Problema XY?

¿Al hacer preguntas, cómo reconozco cuando estoy cayendo en el? ¿Cómo lo evito?

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/)

<sub>Tradución de la entrada del FAQ de SO [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/346768)</sub>

Answer (score 17):

## ¿Qué es?

El [problema](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) [XY](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341) es preguntar sobre la *solución* que has intentado en lugar de sobre cuál es tu problema *real*.

Es decir, estás intentando resolver el problema `X` y crees que la solución `Y` funcionará, pero en lugar de preguntar sobre `X` cuando te encuentras con algún problema, tu pregunta es sobre `Y`.

## El problema

Esto puede conducir a cierta frustración a la gente que intenta ayudarte a resolver el problema ya que, para cuando preguntas sobre el tema, la solución que realmente necesitas puede no tener ninguna conexión obvia con el problema que estás intentando resolver.

## Cómo evitarlo

Para evitar caer en esta trampa, siempre incluye información sobre una imagen más amplia del problema además de cualquier solución que hayas intentado aplicar.  Si alguien te pide más información, o especialmente una pregunta más específica, debes proporcionar más detalles. Si existe alguna otra solución que crees que podría ser sugerida y que ya hayas descartado previamente, no intentes evitar volver a ella - en lugar de eso explica por qué la has descartado, ya que esto da más información sobre tus requerimientos y ayuda a los demás a proporcionar mejores respuestas.

## Un ejemplo

Una conversación de IRC que ilustra este problema:

> **P:** ¿Existe alguna función para devolver el string que hay entre dos delimitadores?
>
> **B:** No entiendo lo que quieres decir, pero dudo que exista una función así.
>
> **C:** `split` y `slice`.
>
> **D:** también `partition`.
>
> **P:** Ya intenté con `partition`.
>
> **P:** Estaba intentado usar funciones incorporadas para obtener el número entre algo como esto en una cadena "atributo1: 50.223, atributo2: 442.1".
>
> **D:** ¿Por qué simplemente no haces un `parse` a la cadena?
>
> **P:** Pensé que existiría algo incorporado para analizar cadenas.
>
> **D:** `pairs = [x.strip() for x in s.split(",")]; attribs = {k: v for x in pairs for k, v in [x.split(": ")]}`
>
> **D:** existen algunas librerías, pero los formatos simples son suficientemente sencillos -- si no debes preocuparte sobre manejo de errores.
>
> **D:** cambiar el origen a un formato conocido, por ejemplo json o yaml, es preferible si es posible.
>
> **P:** Este código en realidad viene de un HTML.
>
> **P:** pero es que no sé cómo analizar Javascript con HTMLParser o como se llame.
>
> **D:** ¿está simplemente incrustado en html, o es alguna versión "corrupta" de html?
>
> **P:** Está incrustado en el HTML.
>
> **D:** si es javascript (y eso parece, excepto por que faltan los corchetes exteriores), json puede probablemente analizarlo.
>
> **P:** gracias.
>
> **D:** No lo he dicho explícitamente: json solo analiza estructuras de datos, no código js.
>
> **P:** Todo lo que necesito analizado es una estructura de datos.

El problema es realmente sobre cómo analizar estructuras de datos de JavaScript, no encontrar "una cadena entre dos delimitadores", y aun así cuesta un poco de tiempo e intuición llegar al problema real.

Esto es más sencillo de hacer en un chat interactivo, pero en un sitio de SE, donde tú pules una publicación un poco, la publicas, y después pasan 5-30 mins, o más, antes de recibir una respuesta, realmente ayuda apuntar en la dirección correcta desde el principio.