# ¿Por qué los votos negativos en una respuesta o una pregunta no va sustentada?

Tags: discusión

Los votos negativos a una respuesta o a una pregunta afectan negativamente la reputación del autor. Sin embargo, al margen de afectar la reputación  no dan un valor agregado porque  no permiten corregir o mejorar al autor. Si me dan votos negativos al menos deberían indicar el motivo. De esta forma se corrigen y perfeccionan respuestas y preguntas. El motivo debería ir al buzón del autor en forma anónima  de lo contrario  lleva a tener muchos comentarios. Es más a cierta cantidad de votos negativos se debería retirar automáticamente del sistema .

He recibido votos negativos pero la verdad no se que estuvo mal. Los votos negativos deberían ser para aprender del error, de lo contrario, puede ser porque a alguien simplemente se le ocurrió

Por otro lado ,;espero que este sea el foro para estos temas.

EDICIÓN: Mi pregunta es más sobre porque votar negativamente sin indicar el motivo. Me dirán que eso dice link ,sin embargo dice muchos  otros. Porque no darle oportunidad al afectado su posición. Bueno, pero me lo aclaro @eyllaesc. Por ejemplo: recibí una sugerencia de respuesta para esta pregunta. No acepte la sugerencia,  sin embargo, me salió un aviso indicando que edite mi pregunta e indique el porqué.  ¿¿Por qué no se aplica lo mismo en este caso?

Comment: Lo que señalas ya ha sido discutida muchas  veces en todos los sitios de SO y la conclusión que es necesario tener un voto anonimo por lo que hasta que SO implemente el comentario anonimo no creo que cambie. Un resumen de porque no justificar lo puedes encontrar en https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin (si no sabes inglés podrias usar google translate). Pero un comentario personal, en mis inicios en SO justificaba mis votos pero desde que un usuario me busco en las redes sociales y me amenazo evito hacerlo

Comment: Quizas alguien se tome el tiempo de traducir la respuesta de la pregunta que enlace para que entiendan todos los motivos de porque el voto es y debe mantenerse anonimo.

Comment: El voto es anónimo y público  y el comentario  de este debería ser tambien anónimo y privado. Es decir recibo el comentario en mi buzon sin saberse quien es Solo me interesa lo que estuvo mal,;de lo contrario, bueno... Gracias..

Comment: ¿Tú pregunta es un requerimiento de una nueva característica o es preguntar por qué el voto es anónimo? Si es lo primero entonces deberias reescribir tu pregunta enfocandolo en ello ya que de lo que leí entiendo que quisiste hacer la segunda pregunta. Por otro lado no creo que seas el primero en querer esa funcionalidad pero desgraciadamente es un proceso  lento y tedioso hasta que la empresa lo implemente(hay miles de feature-request que aun no se han implementado)

Comment: Recomendación de mi parte(no he escrito ninguna pregunta pero si he publicado muchas respuestas): Muestra que sabes del tema en particular señalando desde un principio lo que deseas lograr(no caigas en el [problema XY](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3360)), muestra lo que has intentando aunque esta falle, elimina las cosas innecesarias y provee el mejor MRE que puedas. Tomate al menos media hora(yo diria 1 hora) en analizar si tu pregunta es la mejor que pudiste hacer(buena redacción, ser claro, etc), invita a un amigo que revise y critique tu pregunta.

Comment: Si, de acuerdo pero que puedo quitar o corregir si para mi esta bien? Salvo, que lo ponga como pregunta que también es válido, cierto?

Comment: Justamente ponte en el lugar de la comunidad: borra todos tus prejuicios acerca de la pregunta y piensa si otra persona lo puede entender. Muchas veces los OPs no sé dan cuenta que la comunidad no desea entender su proyecto(es una inversión muy grande que nadie hará) sino tu problema actual, SO no es un servivio de tutoria(se puede aprender pero no es el objetivo del sitio) sino un lugar de Q&A de calidad.

Comment: Ok  Gracias. Son relativamente nuevo y poco a poco voy entiendo la mecánica  Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Queria revisar algunas de tus preguntas pero no veo ninguna, supongo que has recibido downvotes a tus respuestas. Si consideras que es la mejor respuesta que tuviste entonces sientete feliz y relajado ya que si es buena recibiras más upvotes que downvotes. Podrias entrar al chat y pedir que revisen tu Q/A y señalar que te den su punto de vista. Pero tampoco te preocupes muchos por los downvotes: algunos no tienen motivos y son muestras de que estas haciendo un buen trabajo, recuerda la frase: *Ladran, Sancho, señal que cabalgamos* (He recibido downvotes a buenas respuestas)

Comment: Como te digo, soy relativamente nuevo y no es que tenga un montón de negativos, solo que quería saber en qué estoy mal para ir corrigiendo esas cosas, sin embargo, tus comentarios me han ayudado a entender la mecánica de SO. Gracias nuevamente.

Comment: Si quieres mejorar la calidad de tus Q/A te recomiendo revisar y analizar el estilo de respuestas de los miembros tops de las etiquetas a las que te dedicas(java: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/java/topusers , python https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/python/topusers, etc) para que veas la diferencia con tu redacción. Por ejemplo una buena respuesta no solo debe señalar la "respuesta" sino tambien podria indicar porque el intento de solución del OP esta fallando.

Comment: @eyllanesc, de verdad muchas gracias por darte la molestia de revisar mis respuestas  creo que con ello y tus comentarios a  mi pregunta me han aclarado muchas cosas. Espero, que en adelante pueda mejorar y contribuir a que SO mantenga la calidad de siempre.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Por qué he recibido un voto negativo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo)

Comment: Realmente los comentarios de @eyllanesc despejaron  las dudas al respecto.   El link ya lo había visto pero es una lista de posibilidades.

Comment: @eyllanesc,  tus comentarios pasalos como  respuesta y la doy por aceptada.

Comment: Mi pregunta es más sobre porque votar negativamente sin indicar el motiv. Me dirán que eso dice link ,sin embargo dice muchos  otros. Porque no darle oportunidad al afectado su posición. Bueno, pero me lo aclaro @eyllaesc.

Comment: Entiendo lo que quieres decir, como comenta @eyllanesc es por motivos de anonimato. Supongo que uno de los motivos del anonimato es para que no te tomes a personal el voto negativo y se lo devuelvas en sus preguntas respuestas como venganza. Si tienes en cuenta todas las respuestas de la pregunta que te he linkeado difícilmente te darán negativos. Es mas, esos negativos se convertirán en positivos. Una persona que se ha tomado el tiempo de leerse y valorar tu pregunta lo mas seguro es que te vote positivo si la pregunta/respuesta es buena (del mismo modo que te vota negativo si es mala).