# Modularicemos las preguntas para que se pregunte una sola cosa y resulte útil para los siguientes que lo lean

Tags: discusión, preguntas, temática

Veo cada vez más preguntas del tipo *Cómo hago este problema que bla bla*. Es decir, preguntas sobre un ejercicio completo. Sí, preguntas para que hagamos los deberes.

Si están bien planteadas, pueden ser útiles, no hay porqué cerrarlas. Sin embargo, al centrarse en el problema como conjunto acaban siendo solamente útiles para las personas que las publican y, tal vez, para quienes ganan puntitos respondiéndolas.

Para que el sitio sea más útil, creo que deberíamos abstraer estos problemas y convertirlos en problemas modulados.

Por ejemplo, veo la pregunta [Crear usuarios a partir de un fichero en Shell](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/424195/83), que básicamente consiste en:

1. Leer un fichero línea a línea.
2. Crear un nombre en base a cierto contenido.
3. Ejecutar un comando.

Podemos ponernos a correr y resolverlo todo, pero es que resulta que 1) se ha respondido múltiples veces (de hecho, publiqué [una canónica](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/129805/83) al respecto), 3) se ha hecho en [distintas ocasiones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=useradd%20is%3Aq) y probablemente 2) esté en algún lugar.

Por ello, sugiero que ayudemos a dar pistas de los pasos importantes, para que finalmente quede una pregunta específica del tipo *Cómo junto dos cadenas*, *Cómo ejecuto tal comando con ciertos parámetros* o *Cómo recorro un fichero*.
De lo contrario, la lista de preguntas útiles para uno pero inútiles para la comunidad no dejará de crecer.

Comment: No me quedo claro que se espera que hagamos ... ¿editar las preguntas? ¿cambiar los títulos?

Comment: @CandidMoe no hay fórmula única, pero sí: comentar al AP para que mejore y centre la pregunta, referenciar otras preguntas que solucionan parte del problema, editar para que el problema sea más claro, etc. Por supuesto, votar para cerrar como duplicados, crear canónicas, etc.

Comment: Relacionado con el tema, [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/424152/separador-de-miles-c) se puede ver en los comentarios que el OP ha preguntado varias veces por lo mismo

Comment: @NicolasOñate ¡interesante! Me hace pensar en el [Problema XY](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3360/83), que tantas veces ocurre.

Comment: Si fuéramos a solicitar un cola de revisión para las preguntas que podrían requerir ser modularizadas, punto  a aparte de lo que implicaría su implementación ¿qué criterios le daríamos al algoritmo? ¿Cómo se determina que una pregunta está centrada en el conjunto?

Comment: @Rubén gran pregunta. Yo creo que la cola que cumpliría esta misión es la de Triaje. Ya en su momento solicité su incorporación: [Instauremos una cola de revisión “triaje” para que solo las preguntas con cierto nivel entren en la página de inicio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3200/83). Básicamente, para que las preguntas se _curen_ un poco antes de estar listas para responder.

Comment: Estoy muy de acuerdo con la cola de triaje. El problema que veo es que, dado el nivel de participación en la moderación en el sitio últimamente, no se si sería una cola mas que estaría saturada...

Comment: @Pikoh ya... el tema es que estamos antepenúltimos en [% de preguntas respondidas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtefG.png). Esto es [bastante peor que los otros SOxx](https://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true#name). Yo estoy algo desconectado, pero intento gastar mis votos de cierre diarios yendo a los más descarados vía las [Herramientas de moderación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=close), pero da la sensación de que el flujo es tan grande que cada vez nos ahoga más. No sé si los CM van a rebajar el voto de cierre a 3, eso ayudaría bastante...

Comment: Si, lo de la reduccion de los votos de cierre a 3 saldrá (o eso nos han dicho). Esperemos que pronto

Comment: Por cierto, gracias por recordarme que debo pasar mas a menudo por las herramientas de moderacion para echar una mano a cerrar preguntas que se quedan a falta de uno o dos votos de ser cerradas. Intentare ser algo mas constante en eso :)

Comment: @Pikoh lo de "mayor cantidad de votos" es muy útil para ir en modo metralleta. La única pena es que las que ya has votado siguen saliendo. Y nada, gracias a ti por mirarlo, bien debería ser la comunidad la que lo hiciera sin necesidad de usar vuestro tiempo de moderadores.

Comment: Bueno..me he pasado y creo que se ha hecho una buena limpieza. Definitivamente bajar los votos de cierre a 3 ayudará mucho

Comment: Veo que me están cayendo muchos votos, tanto positivos como negativos. Animaos a comentar y así vemos qué os parece. Esto no es un concurso de popularidad, sino una sugerencia que seguro que entre todos podemos pulir, o descartar.

Comment: Si se respondio muchas veces, porque no se marca como duplicado? Por otro lado he visto muchas preguntas asi, solo ponen todo o casi nada del ejercicio que tienen que resolver. La solucion que le veo es que el OP ponga lo que ha intento referenciando "documentacion" para que ayude a otros

Comment: @JuanRivera porque se respondió parte de la pregunta, no entera. Si yo pregunto cómo se cocina una cena de Nochevieja consistente en X, Y y Z, será pregunta nueva. Ahora bien, si la pregunta se convierte en 1) cómo frío algo para X, 2) cómo caliento el horno para Y y 3) cómo escurro el agua para Z, probablemente todas esas mini preguntas sean más útiles para el siguiente que venga. De ahí mi propuesta de convertir las preguntas en las partes pequeñas que sí son aprovechables para otros.

Comment: a mí lo que me hace hervir la sangre son los que agradecen una buena respuesta poniendo una nueva pregunta como comentario :@

Comment: Pero si tú me decías antes que había que responder bien sin mirar a quién. Cómo cambia el mundo ;)  PD. Estoy de acuerdo

Comment: @Alfabravo ¿¿?? Y no creo que me esté contradiciendo :) Mi punto es responder bien, sin mirar a quién pero mirando que la pregunta sea útil para los siguientes que pasen y contribuyan a crear una buena colección.