# Preguntas con respuestas objetivas que son cerradas por "basadas en opiniones". ¿Por qué?

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas, votos-de-reapertura

Recientemente he visto cómo se cerraban dos preguntas (bueno, muchas más, pero estas dos me han sorprendido especialmente):

1. [¿Cómo evitar que mi programa sea plagiado?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/54057/83)
2. [¿Cuál es la convención en Python para los nombres de las variables?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/448690/83)

La primera se resolvió con una respuesta muy extensa, detallada y que provee distintos puntos de vista ciertamente objetivos.

La segunda contiene una autorespuesta en la que se detalla el convenio que tiene Python para el nombre de las variables. Si bien en otros lenguajes eso va a gustos, en Python está muy establecido ([PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)) y, sin ir más lejos, la [pregunta equivalente en SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/q/159720/1983854) tiene cientos de miles de visitas, muchísimos votos y está muy activa.

Sin embargo, ambas han sido cerradas.

¿No estamos llevando demasiado lejos lo de "basado en opiniones"? ¿No sería pertinente valorar las respuestas existentes para determinar si una pregunta es válida? Al fin y al cabo, hablamos de contenido.
La idea de Stack Overflow es crear una obra de referencia para los que vengan después: por ello, creo que es clave identificar preguntas recurrentes y generalizarlas para que cubran el caso genérico. Creo por otra parte que llevamos mal camino si nos empeñamos en responder y volver a responder la misma cosa muy específica dicha de la misma manera. Hablé de esto en [Modularicemos las preguntas para que se pregunte una sola cosa y resulte útil para los siguientes que lo lean](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5006/83) y [¿Cómo gestionar las preguntas que son ejercicios de clase?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4365/83).

Animo, pues, a valorar todas estas cosas y, en el caso específico de las preguntas que enlazo, reabrirlas.

Comment: Yo vote por cerrar una de esas preguntas. Use la etiqueta "basada en opiniones" porque no había otra más apropiada. Mi posición es que SOes no es "Introducción a la Programación I", que conceptos como `for`, `while`, y las convenciones del lenguaje deben ser conocidos. Hay mil tutoriales disponibles que abordan esos temas; no hay necesidad de discutirlos acá también.

Comment: @CandidMoe la idea de SO es la de crear un repositorio de contenido para todos. Idealmente, que todo pueda acabar estando aquí, sin que haya un límite inferior (si no sabes X, no preguntes; si al menos no tienes conocimientos nivel Y, no nos vale). De ahí que en el pasado incluso se creara "Documentation" para cubrirlo de una forma más ágil. Al menos así lo he leído yo siempre y me parece un enfoque más práctico que el poner unos niveles de acceso. Para mí, el corte debe estar en la calidad y utilidad, no en lo básico que pueda ser.

Comment: Voy a dar mi opinion. La primera pregunta mas que basada en opiniones, yo la consideraría demasiado amplia. Hay muchas respuestas posibles, y es un tema creo que demasiado extenso para el sitio, no hay una respuesta concreta. En cuanto a la segunda, creo que tiene un fallo de base, que es su redaccion: _De las siguientes formas de nombrar una variable (o una función), **¿cuál es mejor?**_ que predispone a su cierre como basado en opiniones. Por ultimo decir que enlazas a su equivalente en ingles, pero hay que tener en cuenta que es una pregunta de 2008, cuando el sitio era mucho mas laxo

Comment: Por cierto, analizando la respuesta a la primera pregunta que aludes, yo podría perfectamente argumentar en contra de todos los puntos, en mi opinion son totalmente subjetivos. Hasta tal punto que la industria sigue buscando formas de proteger el codigo, con lo que obviamente ellos no consideran que sea una perdida de tiempo.

Comment: @Pikoh gracias por tus comentarios. Probablemente no debería haber metido las dos preguntas en el mismo saco, veo que mi conocimiento del tema de 1) no es suficientemente amplio como para haberle encontrado las objeciones que comentas. Probablemente pues se podría cerrar pero como demasiado amplia, creo que marcar el motivo correcto ayuda a transmitir un mejor mensaje.

Comment: @Pikoh sobre _enlazas a su equivalente en ingles, pero hay que tener en cuenta que es una pregunta de 2008, cuando el sitio era mucho mas laxo_, soy consciente de ello. Ahora bien, hay mucha gente trabajando muy activamente en cerrar preguntas que caigan en cualquiera de los motivos de cierre actuales. No es raro ver cerrar (¡y eliminar!) preguntas muy antiguas, votadas y respondidas. En este caso no ha sido así ([y mira que lo han intentado en alguna ocasión](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/159720/timeline)).

Comment: Sin duda a veces hay preguntas que se cierran por motivos que no son correctos, pero eso tambien es una limitación de tener pocas opciones a elegir y tener que encajarlas en una lo mas acercada posible. Yo probablemente estaría de acuerdo en cerrarla como demasiado amplia, pero una vez ha sido cerrada por la comunidad yo prefiero que sea la misma comunidad la que decida que hacer y no hacer uso de mis "superpoderes".

Comment: En cuanto al otro tema...si, parece que se ha intentado cerrar y no se ha logrado. Como digo creo que la segunda pregunta podría salvarse con una edición, principalmente eliminando la parte de **¿cuál es mejor?** que puede apelar directamente a opiniones

Comment: Entonces eso seria la respuesta a tu pregunta "*¿Por que?*" no? La primera es porque es muy amplia y no se [mejoro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) en su debido tiempo. La segunda por la palabra "¿Cual es mejor?"

Comment: Fedo, no me tome el trabajo de fijarme, pero la primera pregunta, no es historica? es de la beta privada? yo la reabriria, la protegeria para que no la molesten, y les diria a todos los usuarios que cerraron una pregunta de hace 4 años que conozcan el contexto de cuando se hizo la pregunta!

Comment: @gbianchi no sabia que en ese tiempo se aceptaban las preguntas amplias...entonces, desde cuando ya no se aceptaron?

Comment: @JuanRivera no se aceptaban entonces tampoco, pero había menos moderadores, la comunidad era más nueva y todos estábamos aprendiendo al mismo tiempo. Ahora somos una comunidad más madura, hay más gente participando y preguntas como esa ya no se cuelan por las rendijas. Una pregunta que se hizo hace mucho tiempo y que no se ajusta a las normas del sitio puede cerrarse, pero si es un tema interesante o contiene respuestas que pueden aún ser útiles, se puede marcar como respuesta histórica y de ese modo se "congela".

Comment: Eso mismo he pensado yo muchas veces, hay preguntas que se cierran mecanicamente por que no hay codigo en ellas, pero es que no todas las preguntas tienen porque llevar codigo, tambien hay preguntas teoricas, en la comunidad de habla inglesa hay preguntas teoricas que tienen muchisimos votos positivos, que si se hicieran en la comunidad de habla hispana terminarian con esa misma cantidad de votos pero en negativo o cerradas como dices, creo que estamos confundiendo rigor con otra cosa

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' (nota aparte) Respecto a la pregunta del sitio en inglés, aunque el puntaje a veces es una buena métrica pero debe tomarse en su real contexto, en los inicios de SO los usuarios eran muy proclives a dar votos que ahora no se ven aun cuando la pregunta tenga el mismo nivel.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' (otra nota aparte) Cerrar una pregunta de mucha reputación involucra mucho esfuerzo de parte de la comunidad por lo que la comunidad del sitio en inglés solo se esfuerza para los casos más extremos, para los menos extremos se bloquea para que no tengan más respuestas.

Comment: @eyllanesc la pregunta que menciono solo llegó a +10 hasta pasado un año. Cómo se evoluciona el puntaje de una publicación sería objetivo de tesis doctorales, pues hay tantas heurísticas como personas. En cualquier caso, y siendo como he sido activo en SO bastantes años, no estoy de acuerdo con lo que comentas: constantemente veo preguntas viejas y bien reconocidas que son cerradas y duplicadas.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' yo tambien participo en SOen y más aun participo en la sala de SOCVR donde se discute que post deben ser eliminados(o cerrados) y despues de una discusión indicamos que post deberian eliminarse. Lo señalo porque mientras más puntaje tenga un post más votos se necesitan para cerrarlo(ya no son los usuales 3 votos sino mucho pero muchos más) y muchas veces los moderadores diamantados se tienen que involucrar en esos cierres.

Comment: @eyllanesc las preguntas siempre necesitan el mismo número de votos para cerrarse. En SO, actualmente 3. Lo que necesita de [un número variable de votos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51071/209901) es la eliminación.