# Incluir formato de botones en la ayuda de edición

Tags: discusión, centro-de-ayuda, formato

He visto que algunas preguntas y respuestas incluyen combinaciones de teclado para diferentes funciones.

Después me puse a buscar cómo puedo lograr este formato *(no lo sabía)*, por lo que busqué en Google `stackoverflow key markup` y encontré esta [respuesta aceptada en Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/26208/271772).

Sin embargo, en el [sitio de ayuda para edición](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) no veo "al menos, claramente" cómo dar formato a las combinaciones de teclado como:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd>.

¿Es posible incluir esta información en el sito de ayuda de edición de SOes para que así otros usuarios conozcan de esta funcionalidad de Markdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Respuesta corta

El [artículo de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) en cuestión lo indica "claramente", léelo detenidamente.

## Detalles

He puesto claramente entre comillas porque si fuera suficientemente claro seguramente no hubieras preguntado y no sería necesario leerlo detenidamente, ¿o sí?. En fin, a mí y a muchos se nos han escapado cosas similares y hemos sido varios los que hemos pasado a preguntar algo que está en los artículos de ayuda, lo cual es un buen uso de Meta.

El artículo de ayuda en cuestión incluye lo siguiente:

> #### HTML insertado
>
> Si necesitas hacer algo que Markdown no admite, utiliza HTML. Ten en cuenta que [solo admitimos un subconjunto de HTML muy limitado](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed).
>
> `Para reiniciar tu computadora, presiona <kbd>ctrl </kbd>+ <kbd>alt
>   </kbd>+ <kbd>supr</kbd>.`

Como se puede ver, incluye un ejemplo de uso de la etiqueta `kbd`.

Los detalles del HTML admitido están en el enlace de Meta SE, el cual está inglés y se encuentra listado en [¿Sabes inglés, quieres aportar a la comunidad de SOes y no sabes cómo? ¡Traduce un FAQ!](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1380/65)